# como eu faço para enviar uma mensagem de erro? discord.py

Tags: python, algoritmo

Olá, Eu estava fazendo uma mensagem com o `discord.Embed`, só que eu quero que caso o usuário não envie a mensagem corretamente, o bot envie uma mensagem `Embed` de erro.

eu tentei deste jeito só que o seguinte erro: `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.`

```
@client.command()
async def remcargo (ctx, role: d.Role, user: d.Member):
    embed = d.Embed(
        title='Sucesso',
        description=f"Removido com sucesso {role.mention} from {user.mention}.",
        colour=d.Colour.green()
    )

    fembed = d.Embed(
        title='Erro',
        description=f"Não foi possível realizar o comando, Verifique se digitou corretamente",
        colour=d.Colour.red()
    )
    try:
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            await user.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    except:

        await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está dando esse erro pois no construtor do comando o parametro "user" é obrigatório. Pra deixar opcional ele deve ficar assim: `user: d.Member = None`

Comment: Ok, eu botei esse comando, só que agora está dando outro problema: Unresolved reference "Nothing"

Comment: Me equivoquei, ao invés de `Nothing` é `None`. Editei minha resposta

Comment: Ok! agora funcionou! Muito Obrigado

Comment: Sugiro pesquisar sobre parametros opcionais em funções